# Manually perform a table reload

Tags: ios, uitableview, reload

In my iphone app, I have this delegate method:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region
{
  //lots of logic here, but in the end I do a
  [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

For testing purposes, I want to manually reload the table with dummy data. For this, I have a UIButton, triggering

```
-(IBAction)reloadTable:(id)sender{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Somehow, nothing happens, when I hit the button. I would expect the

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

to be called, but it isn't.

Where is the hole in my reasoning?

Comment: Is the tableview datasource/delegate set ? Does your datasource have any new data in it ? Your reloadTable IBAction simply reloads the table, it doesn't add any more data to the datasource ?

Comment: yes, source and delegate are set. But there might not be new data. I'll return here if I have more info. I assumed that reloaddata would go through the whole tableview delegate methods, regardless of the presence of (new) data

Comment: well it does, but if there's no new data what are you expecting to see

Answer (score 0):

Put a break point within your -(IBAction)reloadTable ..., run the app and tap your button.  If the code does not stop at your breakpoint, you need to connect the "touchUpInside" event of that button to your -(IBAction).

If it does stop at your breakpoint, make sure the tableView itself is not nil, and that the tableView's dataSource is pointing to your viewController.

The IBAction issue is the most likely cause.

Comment: I did the breakpoint. I guess that @CW0007007 is correct in that, that there IS NO new data. I assumed that it would cycle that code anyway.